# db2 query insert from another table

Tags: db2

I have a table product(id_product , name );

I have another one: productHistory (id_H , id_product , name);

I wanna create a query (db2) to insert all the rows of product in productHistory;

I have a sequence product_history_seq

I wanna do something like that:

```
insert into productHistory 
        (id_h ,  , id_product , name) 
  values ( product_history_seq.nextval,..
```

Or,

```
select (id_product , name) from product
```

What's the correct query?

Comment: post your not working, relevant code.

Comment: just I wanna insert all the rows of product in productHistory taking into account the id_h: to insert it I have to use product_history_seq.nextval

Comment: yeah i got that. but you don't want the people to think that u haven't even tried solving that alone, do ya?

Comment: I tried
insert into productHistory (id_h , id_product , name) values ( product_history_seq.nextval,
select (id_product , name) from product );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
insert into  productHistory 
       ( id_h
       , id_product 
       , name
       ) 
  select next value for product_history_seq
       , id_product 
       , name 
    from product 
;
```

Comment: What I was pointing out is the syntax, such as `next value for`

Answer (score 2):

Make id_h auto increment and try this

```
  insert into  productHistory ( id_product , name) values (select id_product , name from product );
```

id_h will auto-increment no need to put it in query

Hope it will help

Comment: That's the problem with db2, I can't set id_h auto increment
I have to create a sequence for it

Comment: @neila what do you mean by sequence, sorry I am not getting?

Comment: for the id_h I have to use its sequence product_history_seq
(product_history_seq.nextval)

Comment: what is product_history_seq.nextval ? Is it a field in productHistory ?

Comment: no, that s allows to insert the id_h using the sequence product_history_seq

Comment: id_h INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO productHistory (id_h, id_product, name)
  (SELECT
    product_history_seq.nextval,
    id_product,
    name
  FROM product);
```

That works

Answer (score 0):

"insert into yourtableone select default, val1, val2 from yourtabletwo" and declare the id as genereated by default

Comment: the id_h is generated by its sequence, how can I integrate it?